# How can i fix steam installation on ubuntu 14.04.3LTS

Tags: steam

First command was `sudo apt-get install steam`

[image]

Second command was `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

[image]

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`,
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install steam`

Comment: still same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just download the .deb file from Steam's website and install it using the Ubuntu Software Center.

You can download the .deb file here: http://store.steampowered.com/about/

Comment: is there another way to do?

Comment: @BeGood Ubuntu has official documentation on installation and common issues with installing the Steam client. You can find it here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sudo apt-get install -f steam`.
The `-f` option resolve dependencies and fix broken packages.

Comment: Still same errors